# Spring 3 Properties File Per Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering if Spring has a properties files mechanism similar to Struts2 where it looks for a properties file first in the same package as the controller and then moves up the package structure until it finds the properties file or property.

I want to define a property file per controller, but I rather not have to wire them up together, if possible. Is there some convention that can be followed that would associate the properties file with the controller? The properties file resolution should also work correctly when resolving locales.

For example, if I define a property called "title" in several prop files, I want the correct one to resolve in the JSP based on which controller handled the request.

```
ControllerA RETURNS ViewA USES PropA.title

ControllerB RETURNS ViewB USES PropB.title
```

I was successful in auto wiring a Property file to a controller's Model attribute and display values in JSP. I was also able to specify a ResourceBundleMessageSource in the configuration and then display values from it in JSP.

Comment: Are you doing that for I18N purposes, or is it for a different manner?

Comment: I definitely want I18N, but currently, I would have to maintain a unique property key across the whole application. Otherwise, the first key loaded would take precedence. What is the typical approach in Spring when you have say many many property files?

Comment: if you need i18n - use tools made for i18n  :) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, not that I know of.... but you can easily write one, if that's what you really want!

Spring has things like BeanFactoryPostProcessor which lets you do things like this with your BeanFactory/ApplicationContext. I'm thinking BeanFactoryPostProcessor would fit the bill here - you could 'post process' a bean by looking for a properties file on the classpath, grabbing the properties, and applying them to the bean.

I'll say this though - Spring is usually meant to be fairly non-invasive. If you want something like this to become part of your design, you might want to think of a way to do this in pure Java, rather than using Spring. For example, create your own Factory and implement and unit test it separately. Require your app to use this Factory to get your business objects.

In other words, you can probably do it in Spring - but it isn't always the best approach. It does sound like it could be the most convenient, in your case, but I haven't see the details of what you're setting and where. Just food for thought..